Stockfish with python-chess on ubuntu
I want to use Stockfish with a simple chess python program I am writing on Ubuntu.  It uses the python-chess library and is text based at the moment.
There are various references to installation including some here but I’m a bit lost as none seem to fully work.  I’ve tried
sudo apt-get install stockfish 

Which all works fine however I understand I also need to reference a chess engine executable.  I went to the stockfish website and downloaded a tar file which I have decompressed into a folder and called it stockfish.  I put this in my program folder so is essentially a sub directory.
There is an example on the python-chess library website which looks like this:
import chess
import chess.engine

engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci(r"C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\stockfish_14_win_x64\stockfish_14_win_x64_avx2.exe")

board = chess.Board()
while not board.is_game_over():
     result = engine.play(board, chess.engine.Limit(time=0.1))
     board.push(result.move)

engine.quit()`

This is a windows example I think as has a .exe file.
When I decompress the tar file I get a bunch of files but I’m not familiar with Linux enough to know which of the decompressed files to reference as the chess engine. Has anyone done this that can help??

Here you can find an example under linux with a Stockfish version installed with apt-get:
engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci("/usr/bin/stockfish")
/usr/bin/stockfish is the path to the Stockfish executable you installed with apt-get.
In any case I find this question much more related to programming than to chess.
